# JSON deserializing

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am trying to deserializing JSON file which looks like:

```
{"dataset":{"id":14686248,
"dataset_code":"EURUSD",
"database_code":"ECB",
"name":"EUR vs USD Foreign Exchange Reference Rate",
"description":"Euro (EUR) vs. US Dollar (USD) reference exchange rate. Foreign exchange reference rates are published by the European Central Bank.  Reference rates are usually updated by 3:00pm CET, based on a regular daily concertation procedure between various central banks across Europe and around the world.  This procedure normally takes place at 2:15pm CET.  Reference rates are mid-market rates, calculated as averages of the buying and selling rate; they do not necessarily reflect actual transaction rates.  Euro foreign exchange reference rates are always quoted using the 'certain' method (i.e EUR 1 = X foreign currency units, where X is the published reference rate).",
"refreshed_at":"2016-12-01T23:16:13.829Z",
"newest_available_date":"2016-12-01",
"oldest_available_date":"1999-01-04",
"column_names":["Date","Value"],
"frequency":"daily",
"type":"TimeSeries",
"premium":false,
"limit":null,
"transform":null,
"column_index":null,
"start_date":"1999-01-04",
"end_date":"2016-12-01",
"data":[["2016-12-01",1.0627]
,["2016-11-30",1.0635],
...
}}
```

Here what i have done:

```
 class request
    {
        [JsonProperty("dataset")]
        public dataset dataset { get; set; }
    }

 class dataset
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string dataset_code { get; set; }
        public string database_code { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string refreshed_at { get; set; }
        public DateTime newest_available_date { get; set; }
        public string[] column_names { get; set; }
        public string frequency { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public DateTime oldest_available_date { get; set; }
        public bool premium { get; set; }
        public string column_index { get; set; }
        public DateTime start_date { get; set; }
        public DateTime end_date { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public List<innerdata> data { get; set; }
    }
 class Data
    {
        public List<innerdata> data { get; set; }
    }
 class innerdata
    {
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public double rate { get; set; }



static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    string result = client.GetStringAsync(MakeQuery()).Result;
                    var weatherData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<request> (result);
                }



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occured: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

And it ends with an error :

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
>   'ApiTest.innerdata' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g.
>   {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either
>   change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the
>   deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection
>   interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be
>   deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added
>   to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. Path
>   'dataset.data[0]', line 1, position 1122.

Answer (score 1):

It's to do with data
`"data":[["2016-12-01",1.0627] ,["2016-11-30",1.0635],`
As it stands this is an array of array's without a key pair. Should be more like the below

```
"data":[{"date": "2016-12-01","rate":1.0627}
,{"date":"2016-11-30","rate":1.0635}]
```

Comment: but i get this JSON file via API and i cant change it

Comment: Then your model is slightly wrong, you can copy the Json. Using visual studio you can then click edit > paste special > Json as class. This should create the model you need.

Comment: It will output data as public List<List<object>> data { get; set; } @codingyoshi beat me to it

Comment: @ChristianP upvoting your answer because that should have helped the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[JsonProperty( "data" )]
public List<List<object>> data { get; set; }
```

In your json in data, you have an array which has an array inside it. The array inside has a datetime at index 0 and a number with decimal at index 1. In C# you cannot have an array with 2 types (date and number). You can use `List<object>` instead.